# Finding smallest polygon covering a set of points in a grid

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Firstly, I'm not asking for code, I just want clarification about my approach.

Secondly, if this isn't totally SO related, I will move the question to the most relevant Stack Exchange site. I'm pretty sure this is a graph theory related problem.

So I have an infinitely large grid with a defined point (0,0)

Each intersection between horizontal/vertical lines in the grid defines another point (given by the number of lines from the origin).

Given a set of points `(x,y)` where each `x,y` is an Integer: return the perimeter of the smallest polygon surrounding the points.

Constraints:

- The number of points is less than 100,000
- The points cannot lie on the perimeter of the polygon.
- The sides of the polygon can only correspond to vertical/horizontal lines in the grid, or a diagonal line in a single square.

My guess that the is a Graph Theory related problem. Just like the Travelling Salesman, I first need to find the shortest path between all points using an algorithm which gives an optimal solution. Then I need to perform the same algorithm between each point to find the optimal path along the grid between the points.

I have written an algorithm for the Travelling Salesman given 80 towns.

In this question there can be 100,000 points. So that makes me wonder if a possible algorithm even exists to solve such a huge number of Nodes.

Is there another approach. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Without thinking about graph theory or coding or algorithm at all, I remember from geometry that a polygon should fit nicely inside a circle. So based on that what you are looking for is a circle. But then again you didn't say **regular polygon** but just polygon. And so perhaps my circle idea won't work. But +1, good question. And yes, there is a coding solution. But it may be dynamic programing as opposed to Greedy algorithm.

Comment: Your problem is not well specified. Because the smallest polygon containing all points has an area which is empty (it is just the shortest graph). Did you mean to find the convex hull of the given points?

Comment: Have you got time or memory constraints?

Comment: I think there is no reason to go through all the points. As mentioned before me, the *convex hull* seems to be the real question here. Consider having 100 points in the first `10x10` square from `(0,0)`. these 100 points could surrounded (assuming you can't "touch" them) by the lines connecting `(-1,-1), (-1,11), (11,11), (11,-1)` in order to create a square

Comment: How about drawing a polygon that is sure to include all the points (like a square using the top-, right-, bottom- and leftmost point) and then repeatedly running through all the polygon's points one by one and pushing them inwards one grid cell at a time until they bump into points?

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. From what you have suggested my next approach will be to find the convex hull of the set of points. Then for each side of the polygon (convex hull) I will determine the shortest length along the grid. Hence, the smallest perimeter. Correct me if this is a bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

The `Convex hull` is not actually necessary to solve this problem.

The most time efficient `convex hull` algorithm is `O(nlogh)`, where `n` is the number of points overall, and `h` is the number of points on the hull.

Looking through the comments above, `m69` nailed it! The algorithm he describes (with a bit extra on top) can be achieved in `O(n)` time. Scrap the `Convex Hull` idea!!

- Draw the minimum square such that it surrounds all the points given. This is done using max & min on the list of points
- For each corner in the square, draw the allowed diagonal line which is closest to the most outer point. This is done by looping through the points and using the euclidean perpendicular distance formula. This is `O(n)`
- Using the intersections between the original square and the diagonal lines, calculate the overall perimeter of the polygon.

Here is my version of the algorithm (written in python). People are free to comment or optimise it if they wish. It was a fun problem to solve.

```
from math import *
N = int(raw_input())
pts = []

for i in xrange(N):
    p1,p2 = map(int, raw_input().split(' '))
    pts.append((p1,p2))

def isBetween(a, b, c):
    ab = sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)
    ac = sqrt((a[0]-c[0])**2 + (a[1]-c[1])**2)
    bc = sqrt((b[0]-c[0])**2 + (b[1]-c[1])**2)
    return abs(ac + bc - ab) < 0.01  # epsilon precision, needs < 1 in grid case

def getPoints(c):

    lines = [(-1, c[0][1]+c[0][0]),(1, c[1][1]-c[1][0]),(-1,c[2][1]+c[2][0]),(1,c[3][1]-c[3][0])]
    maxes = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]

    for count, line in enumerate(lines):

        pdist = (abs(line[0]*CH[0][0] - CH[0][1] + line[1]))/(sqrt((line[0]*line[0]) + 1 ))
        maxes[count][0] = pdist
        maxes[count][1] = CH[0]

    for elem in CH[1:]:

        for count, line in enumerate(lines):

            pdist = (abs(line[0]*elem[0] - elem[1] + line[1]))/(sqrt((line[0]*line[0]) + 1 ))
            if pdist < maxes[count][0]: 
                maxes[count][0] = pdist
                maxes[count][1] = elem

    for greg in range(4):
        maxes[greg][1] = list(maxes[greg][1])

    maxes[0][1][0] -=1
    maxes[1][1][0] +=1
    maxes[2][1][0] +=1
    maxes[3][1][0] -=1

    gregarr = []

    for i in range(4):

        y = lines[i][0]*(c[i][0]-maxes[i][1][0]) + maxes[i][1][1]
        cornerdist = abs(c[i][1] - y)

        if i == 0:
            gregarr.append((c[i][0], c[i][1]+cornerdist))
            gregarr.append((c[i][0]+cornerdist, c[i][1]))
        elif i == 1:
            gregarr.append((c[i][0]-cornerdist, c[i][1]))
            gregarr.append((c[i][0], c[i][1]+cornerdist))
        elif i == 2:
            gregarr.append((c[i][0], c[i][1]-cornerdist))
            gregarr.append((c[i][0]-cornerdist, c[i][1]))
        else:
            gregarr.append((c[i][0]+cornerdist, c[i][1]))
            gregarr.append((c[i][0], c[i][1]-cornerdist))

    return gregarr

def distance(p0, p1):

    return ((p0[0] - p1[0])*(p0[0] - p1[0]) + (p0[1] - p1[1])*(p0[1] - p1[1]))**(0.5)

def f7(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [ x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

CH = pts
H = len(CH)

if H == 0:
    print('0.000')
elif H == 1:
    print('5.656')
else:
    per = 0
    minx = min(CH, key = lambda x: x[0])[0]-1
    miny = min(CH, key = lambda x: x[1])[1]-1
    maxx = max(CH, key = lambda x: x[0])[0]+1
    maxy = max(CH, key = lambda x: x[1])[1]+1
    corners = [(minx,miny),(maxx, miny),(maxx,maxy),(minx,maxy)]
    arr = getPoints(corners)
    arr = f7(arr)
    arr.append(arr[0])
    T = len(arr)

    for i in range(1,T):

        per += distance(arr[i-1], arr[i])

    print(per)
```